# How to set the offset/pointer to a list/array in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

Ironically I have made this program successfully in x86 ASM but I'm having major trouble with implementing it in Python.

I have only just started learning a high level language. Here is a snippet:

```
rn_table = [0x63, 0x06, 0xF0, 0x23, 0xF8, 0xE5, 0xA8, 0x01, 0xC1, 0xAE, 0x7F, 0x48,
0x7B, 0xB1, 0xDC, 0x09, 0x22, 0x6D, 0x7D, 0xEE, 0x9D, 0x58, 0xD5, 0x55, 0x24, 0x39, 0x7A, 0xDF,
0x8E, 0x54, 0x6C, 0x1B, 0xC0, 0x0B, 0xD0, 0x43, 0xD8, 0x9A, 0x47, 0x5D, 0x21, 0x02, 0x17, 0x4B,
0xDB, 0x11, 0xAF, 0x70, 0xCD, 0x4D, 0x34, 0x49, 0x72, 0x91, 0x2D, 0x62, 0x97, 0x59, 0x45, 0xF7,
0x6E, 0x46, 0xAA, 0x0A, 0xA3, 0xC8, 0x31, 0x92, 0x38, 0xFA, 0xD4, 0xE6, 0xCB, 0xF3, 0xDE, 0x6B,
0xBB, 0xF1, 0x1C, 0x3C, 0xD6, 0xAD, 0xB2, 0xA9, 0xDD, 0x57, 0x42, 0x95, 0x0C, 0x79, 0x25, 0x1F,
0xBC, 0xE7, 0xAC, 0x5B, 0x83, 0x28, 0x76, 0xF2, 0x18, 0xDA, 0x87, 0xA1, 0x61, 0x6F, 0xBE, 0x5A,
0x5E, 0x51, 0xEF, 0xB0, 0xC9, 0x15, 0x74, 0x89, 0xBD, 0xD1, 0xA2, 0x75, 0xD7, 0x99, 0x85, 0x4C,
0x4F, 0xD2, 0xBF, 0x4A, 0x20, 0x08, 0x56, 0xA0, 0x50, 0x3A, 0x67, 0x26, 0x41, 0x33, 0xB7, 0xBA,
0xFB, 0x30, 0xCF, 0x7C, 0x84, 0x2C, 0x32, 0xE9, 0x1D, 0x16, 0x82, 0x78, 0xA4, 0x80, 0x65, 0x5F,
0x0E, 0x27, 0xB9, 0x19, 0xC3, 0xA7, 0xB6, 0x00, 0x3B, 0xFC, 0x88, 0xE1, 0xC6, 0x93, 0xFE, 0x8B,
0xD9, 0xB8, 0x13, 0x69, 0x2F, 0x64, 0x12, 0x37, 0xFD, 0x77, 0xE2, 0xB5, 0x04, 0xE0, 0x1A, 0x8C,
0x8F, 0xB4, 0xCC, 0xF9, 0x60, 0xEB, 0x29, 0xE3, 0x90, 0xA5, 0x68, 0x3D, 0x81, 0x73, 0x3F, 0xAB,
0x7E, 0xB3, 0x0F, 0xCE, 0xC4, 0x35, 0x94, 0x96, 0x86, 0x71, 0xD3, 0x2A, 0xE4, 0x9F, 0x9C, 0xEC,
0x4E, 0x14, 0xF5, 0xEA, 0x40, 0xA6, 0xF6, 0x03, 0x98, 0xC5, 0x07, 0xF4, 0x2B, 0xC2, 0x3E, 0xE8,
0x9B, 0x36, 0x53, 0x2E, 0x8D, 0x0D, 0x52, 0x10, 0x66, 0x1E, 0xED, 0x8A, 0x44, 0x9E, 0x05, 0xFF,
0x5C, 0xC7, 0x6A, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x12, 0x19, 0x21, 0x27, 0x2D, 0x35, 0x3D, 0x49, 0x51, 0x5A,
0x62, 0x69, 0x72, 0x7A, 0x83, 0x8B, 0x94, 0x9D, 0xA5, 0xAB, 0xB2, 0xB9, 0xC1, 0xC9, 0xD2, 0xD9,
0xDE, 0xE3, 0xE8, 0xED, 0xF5]


cluck = 16
clevel = 12
enemy_level = 10

crit_pc = (cluck + clevel - enemy_level) / 4

offset2 = 0
offset3 = 0

rnd1 = 0
rnd2 = 0
rnd0 = 0

crit_rnd = 0

lookups = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
lookup_main = 0


def rng_go():
    global lookup_main
    lookups[lookup_main] = offset2      # lookup_main chooses lookups item. position = offset2
    lookups[lookup_main] += 1           # increase the lookups chosen value by 1 (previously offset2)
    rn_table[offset2] = rnd1            # choose value from rn_table, position of value is offset2

    if crit_pc == 0:
        print "No critical\n"
    lookup_main += 1                    # increment lookup_main by 1
    lookup_main = lookup_main and 7     # check lookup_main < 8
    lookups[lookup_main] = offset3      # lookup_main chooses another lookups item. position = offset3
    lookups[lookup_main] += 1           # increase lookups chosen value by 1
    rn_table[offset3] = rnd2            # choose value from rn_table, position of value is offset3
    # calculate critical%
    rnd2 * 256
    rnd0 = rnd1 or rnd2
    rnd0 = rnd0 and 65535
    crit_rnd = ((rnd0 * 99) / 65535) + 1
    if crit_pc >= crit_rnd:
        print "Critical hit success!\n"
        print "crit_rnd: %d \t crit_pc: %d" % (crit_rnd, crit_pc)
        print "rnd1: %d \t rnd2: %d" % (rnd1, rnd2)
        print "lookups: %r" % (lookups)
    else:
        print "No critical\n"
        print "crit_rnd: %d \t crit_pc: %d" % (crit_rnd, crit_pc)
        print "rnd1: %d \t rnd2: %d" % (rnd1, rnd2)
        print "lookups: %r" % (lookups)
rng_go()
```

I want to use lookup_main as a kind of pointer to the lookups list.
So, position 0 in lookups is 0. Position 1 is 2, and so on.

I want to therefore increase this pointer/offset, but I am clearly doing it wrong.

**How can I increment the offset to the list?** I don't want to directly manipulate any numbers in the list. I just want to change the offset.

Actually, now that I think about it... it seems I'm stuck thinking in the 'Assembly' way of doing things >.< Hope this goes away... I'm unable to think 'big picture' >.<''''

The (dis)assembly that works is like:

```
lw r3,0x00d4(r28)      # load word from 80062e18 = offset1
lui r2, 0x8006
addiu r2,r2,0x2e10      # 80062e10
addu r3,r3,r2         # 80062e10 + (word from 80062e18 as offset)
lbu r2,0x0(r3)         # load byte from 80062e10(offset1) = offset2
nop

addiu r4,r2,0x01      
andi r2,r2,0xff
sb r4,0x0(r3)         # increment by 1 and store

lui r1,0x8008
addu r1,r1,r2         # 80083084
lbu r2,0x3084(r1)      # load byte from 80083084(offset2) = rnd1
jr r31
nop

lw r3,0x0008(r28)      # load word from 80062d4c
nop

addiu r4,r3,0x01      # increment by 1

andi r3,r3,0x07         # AND 7 (check that value < 8)
sw r4,0x08(r28)         # store incremented value back to 8062d4c


beq r3,r0,0x14c18      # if crit% = 0 then no critical
addu r16,r2,r0         # move rnd1
jal 0x14b54
nop

lw r2,0xd4(r28)         # load word from 80062e18
nop
addiu r2,r2,0x01      # increment by 1
andi r2,r2,0x07         # AND with 7 (check that value < 8) = offset2
sw r2,0xd4(r28)         # store in 80026e18
jr r31
nop

jal 0x14b70
nop

lw r3,0xd4(r28)         # load word from 80062e18 = offset3
lui r2,0x8006
addiu r2,r2,0x2e10      
addu r3,r3,r2         
lbu r2,0x0(r3)         # load byte from 80062e10(offset3) = offset4
nop

addiu r4,r2,0x01      
andi r2,r2,0xff         
sb r4,0x0(r3)         # increment byte by 1 and store in 80062e11

lui r1,0x8008         
addu r1,r1,r2         
lbu r2,0x3084(r1)      # load byte from 80083084(offset4) = rnd2
jr r31
nop

andi r2,r2,0xff         
sll r2,r2,0x08         # rnd2 * 256
andi r3,r16,0xff      
or r2,r3,r2         # rnd1 OR rnd2 (combine rnd1 and rnd2) = rnd0
lw r31,0x14(r29)
lw r16,0x10(r29)
addiu r29,r29,0x18
jr r31
nop

lw r31,0x10(r29)
andi r2,r2,0xffff      # take 2 bytes of rnd0
jr r31
addiu r29,r29,0x18


## calculate crit_rnd for which to compare against crit% ##

lui r4,0x8000
ori r4,r4,0x8001      
andi r2,r2,0xffff      
sll r3,r2,0x01         
addu r3,r3,r2         
sll r2,r3,0x05         ## Just: crit_rnd = ((rnd0 * 99) / 65535) + 1
addu r3,r3,r2         
mult r3,r4         
addu r2,r5,r3         
sra r2,r2,0x0f         
sra r3,r3,0x1f         
subu r2,r2,r3         
lw r31,0x10(r29)
addiu r2,r2,0x01      
jr r31
addiu r29,r29,0x0018      

slt r2,r16,r2         
bne r2,r0,0xb0888      # if crit% >= crit_rnd then critical hit success
nop
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect the effect of calling your function to be? It doesn't return anything, and it's not clear to me what you want it to do. Also, what is `offset2`, which isn't defined anywhere?

Comment: @Blckknght I have edited my post to include more information.
I want to program a random number lookup table

Comment: It's going to take me a while to try to understand your assemby code, but if the purpose is just to generate a random number, there are much better ways to accomplish that. Python's `random` module offers a variety of ways to generate random values. This is one of the big advantages of high-level languages: many common problems have already been solved and there are easy ways to reuse the solutions.

Comment: @Blckknght No problem. That's ok. I'm trying to reverse engineer this RNG. I just wish to access an array/list in python but I don't know the syntax. I can't find it anywhere... :p

Comment: @Blckknght in C-like pseudocode it is as easy as: {
  int rnd1;
  rnd1 = return byte_0x83084[byte_0x62e10[word_0x62e18]++];
}

Comment: "and" is logical. Use bitwise "&". The same with "or"..."|". To see the difference, type in python "4 and 8" and "4 & 8".

Answer (score 0):

List access in Python is not very complicated. [The Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) has some decent introductory examples.

To read a value from a list, just provide a suitable index:

```
list_name[index]
```

To assign the value to a variable, just use an assignment statement:

```
some_var = list_name[index]
```

To write a value into a list, just turn the assignment statement around:

```
list_name[index] = some_value
```

I think you had a few of your assignments backwards.

The other major issue you had was due to using the logical `or` and `and` operators instead of the bitwise `|` and `&` operators. The former won't do what you want, in most cases.

Here's some fixed code. I've omitted the `offset` values, since they're not really needed:

```
rnd1 = rn_table[lookups[lookup_main]]
lookups[lookup_main] += 1

lookup_main += 1
lookup_main &= 7   # doing %= 8 might be more clear

rnd2 = rn_table[lookups[lookup_main]]
lookups[lookup_main] += 1

rnd2 *= 256        # or use <<= 8 to left shift instead of multiplying

rnd0 = rnd1 | rnd2
rnd0 &= 65535      # this step should be unnecessary
```

Two values in the `lookups` list will be incremented by running this, which I assume is a desired side effect. `lookup_main` will also be incremented once, wrapping around if it goes above 7.

As I commented in the code, some of the bitwise operations might be more clear if you used different operators (with the same effects). This is a style judgement, so your mileage may vary.

Using the modulus operator `%` in the logic to increment `lookup_main` may be a bit clearer that you're forcing it to wrap around to zero if it reaches 8. Similarly, left shifting `rnd2` with the `<<` operator may be more clear than doing a multiplication. I'd also suggest using hexidecimal for any constants you use in bitwise operations (so `0xFFFF` instead of `65535`).